# Blazor The URI 'https://mydomain.tk/login' is not contained by the base URI

Tags: apache, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a problem that non of the pages work, only index page.
It works on my own machine (when testing in visual studio), but when hosting on a linux ubuntu machine with apache2 this error appears.

The webpage used to be server hosted client model (and it was working fine, no problems at all, just slow), but now that I changed it to server only (that works with SignalR) it doesn't work anymore.

I managed to fix websocket connection in apache settings so it's connecting.
Only when trying to go to another page for example /login
this happens: 
[image]

feel free to try https://miniturtle.tk

using version 3.0.0-preview5

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

I think it's the apache config files.

/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-FatGo.service:

```html
[Unit]
Description=FatGo
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/FatGo/publish
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/FatGo/publish/FatGo.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-demo
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/FatGo.conf:

```html
<VirtualHost *:443>  
ServerName miniturtle.tk
ServerAlias www.miniturtle.tk
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
  
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 connectiontimeout=28800 timeout=28800 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC] 
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]
  
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/FatGo-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/FatGo-access.log common
LimitRequestFieldSize 10000000
LimitRequestBody 10000000
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/FatGo.conf:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/FatGo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/FatGo-access.log common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!RC4
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

If you could help me with this, I would appreciate it very much :)
Thanks for reading

P.S. I'm not a experienced web developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that the scheme of the base URI is http, whereas the scheme for the login url is https? I've no knowledge of Ubuntu, but it seems as though you'll have to adjust some settings in your app's config files.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice :).

I removed the SSL from the page and it started working

Comment: it would be great , if we could work out how to make it work with SSL.  i have the same issue.